# Can't assign html .src to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm trying to switch an image on a HTMLbutton using javascript.

It works, but I think it loads the image every time I click the button, and that's not good. So I want to load the images only one time and than I can switch between the images.
This Is what I have now.

```
mute.onclick=function () {

if (audioEngine.isMuted)
    {
    document.getElementById('muteIcon').src="images/unmuted.png";
    }       
         else{
           document.getElementById('muteIcon').src="images/unmuted.png";
             }
```

But I think every time I click the button it looks in the path "images/unmuted.png" to see what's there and load it. So I was thinking this is an easy fix. I just define a variable unmuteImage and assign that to document.getElementById('muteIcon').src. Like this

```
var unmuteImage=new Image();
    unmuteImage.src='images/unmuted.png';

mute.onclick=function () {

if (audioEngine.isMuted)
    {
    document.getElementById('muteIcon').src=unmuteImage;
    }       
         else{
           document.getElementById('muteIcon').src="images/unmuted.png";
             }
```

But when I do this, I get the following error in my consols:

```
GET file:///path/to/the/mian/html/file/[object%20HTMLImageElement]  (In red text)
```

And I don't get the image, I get the "borken image" picture because somehow it didn't find the picture.

Can somebody help me please?
Thanks

Comment: Put two `<img>` tags beside eachother, and use the CSS `display` property to only display the correct image, e.g., when `isMuted === true`, show one of the img tags, and vice versa.

Comment: It shouldn't need to load the images each time, they should be cached and it will reuse the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may work for you if you have jquery

```
$('#muteIcon').replaceWith(unmuteImage);
```

other wise you have to use src itself

```
document.getElementById('muteIcon').src = unmuteImage.src;
```

Comment: Thank you, the src works! :D but the replaceWith works only one time. it's strange. It stays on muted icon and doesn't go back to unmuted icon. No error. Strange...